# Probability that sum of four number equal 50.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this question:

> We choose 4 numbers randomly with replacement from the space $\{0,1,2,3,...,50\}.$
>
> a) What is the probability that the sum of the numbers is exactly 50?
>
> b) What is the probability that the sum of the numbers is exactly 50 and all numbers are bigger or equal to 10?

For (a): I tried to calculate the probability that the first three numbers are less or equal to 50, then multiplying the answer by $1/50.$

But I am stuck on calculating the probability. Is my approach good? any hints?

For (b): I don't have any clue what to do.

Comment: Do you know about stars and bars? If so, you can use it on part (a) to count the number of ways four numbers can sum to $50$.

Answer (score 2):

a)

The set $\Omega=\{0,1,2,\dots,50\}^4$ can be used as outcome space and has cardinality $51^4$.

The events $\{\omega\}$ where $\omega\in\Omega$ are equiprobable.

So the probability will equal $51^{-4}|A|$ where $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3+\omega_4=50\}$.

The cardinality of $A$ can be found by means of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and equals $\binom{50+3}{3}$.

b)

Similar story, but now we are looking for the cardinality of $B=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3+\omega_4=50\text{ and }\omega_i\geq10\text{ for } i=1,2,3,4\}$

Setting $\alpha_i=\omega_i-10$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ we find that $B$ has the same cardinality as the set $C=\{\alpha\in\Omega\mid\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4=10\}$

Again we can apply stars and bars. This time we find that $|B|=\binom{10+3}3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Denote your 4 numbers by: x$_1, x_2,x_3$  and $x_4$**
Total number of selections is $$51^4$$

**For** **a**:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=50$$ (where all $x_i$ lie in {0,1,,...,50})

> So, using stars and bars method, number of solutions of above equation are: $$^{50+4-1}C_{4-1}=^{53}C_3$$ So, probability will be: $$\frac{^{53}C_3}{51^4}$$

**For b: the set shrinks to {10,11,12,...,50}**

So, $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=50$$ (where all $x_i$ are $\geq10$)

So, replace all $x_i$ with $(10+y_i)$ such that $y_i \geq 0$ $\forall$ **i** $\in{1,2,3,4}$

> So, $$(10+y_1)+(10+y_2)+(10+y_3)+(10+y_4)=50$$
>   Or, $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=10$$ number of solutions is: $$^{10+4-1}C_{4-1}=^{13}C_3$$
>   So, probability will be: $$\frac{^{13}C_3}{51^4}$$

Comment: yeah...so, $51^4$?